# populating spinner using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I have a list of custom objects, that I created from downloaded JSON array and I would like to populate the `Spinner` with just one field from my list, but I still want to keep the whole `onItemSelected`.
Currently I am doing it like that

```
ArrayAdapter<Country> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Country>(Prototype_activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ValueHolder.countryList)
                spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

So how do I say to adapter to use only one field from each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...and I would like to populate the Spinner with just one field from my
>   list, but I still want to keep the whole onItemSelected.

If you are going to use an `ArrayAdapter` then implement the `toString()` method for the `Country` class to return a `String` representation of the desired field.